# jquery smooth variable scroll to element id

Tags: jquery, scroll, smoothing

I am using the following script to scroll the user to an element. It works nicely, but I was wondering if there was a way I could make the scroll a bit smoother.

At the moment it scrolls at a set speed, but I was hoping it could accelerate to speed and then decelerate to a stop to give a much smoother experience.

Could anyone advise me on how to do this?

Many thanks

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#elementtoScrollToID").offset().top
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include jQuery UI / [jQuery easing](https://jqueryui.com/easing/). This will allow you to use the different easing options provided, i.e:

```
$(function(){
$('#button').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#elementtoScrollToID").offset().top
    }, 1000, 'easeOutCubic');
});
});
```

Comment: I tried that and it stopped working all together. Im using Zurb Foundation 5 so maybe something is clashing?

Comment: Foundation should not cause a clash. what does your console say? You should include jQuery before [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/download/).
if in doubt, feel free to show how you include jQuery on your page.

Comment: I found it, it wasn't loading the JQuery UI js script properly. All working now, many thanks for your help!